# Computer crashed for good

Tags: windows-7, crash, hardware-failure, boot

My one-year-old custom PC was crashing when I played Battlefield for 5 minutes or Counter-Strike for 20 minutes. Now it keeps crashing whenever I power it up. (It doesn't loop.)

Debugging steps

1. I tried changing the PSU with a good one (700 Watts cooler master) to test it.
2. I cleared the CMOS.
3. I tried testing each RAM individually and swapping the slots. It still crashes
4. Now the computer crashes within 1 second of powering it up; it even doesn't go into the BIOS beeps.
5. (New) Tried to swap for and old GPU (current is Gtx 660) --> works until the windows logo
6. (New) Swapped for a newer GPU (Gtx 770) same problem, crashes before POST

I am suspecting the CPU or the motherboard to be the problem, but how can I be sure without paying a tech to inspect my PC?

Comment: Did it ever give POST beep codes in the past?  Try this, unplug all optical and hard drives, remove all add-in cards, and remove the RAM entirely and turn it on.  Without RAM, the board should toss out beep codes - if it doesn't give beep codes, then you've got bad hardware.

Comment: Of course, to get beep codes there must be a speaker attached, or an on-board beeper.

Comment: Possible reasons: One of heatsinks hanging instead of being firmly attached; water cooling system leaked; some device short-circuits (maybe the mobo itself) try disconnecting all of them; capacitors evaporated and mobo is unusable; CPU fried (possibly because cooling was insufficient)

Comment: Yes it did POST beeps before until recently it stopped.
I removed everything 
I get the Long Short Short beeps from the motherboard. So I guess the CPU is dead right?

Comment: I agree with @Kitet and I even would disassemble system block, take the motherboard off the case, assemble it back on the table (workbench?) power it up and carefully examine every part of the motherboard and its components (of course if it does not void warranty or not too risky by any other means for you).

Comment: @Conrad If you get beeps then cpu is OK. Get motherboard manual and see in Troubleshooting what does this sequence mean. Probably that you have no memory or GFX. If you have no manual then replace components one by one and see when beeping stops and computer is again `crashing`, then there's your culprit.

Comment: @Kitet  Ok thanks, I added the RAM ( I got beeps for: Graphics card issue), then I added the GPU (Gtx 660 Ti) and the computer crashed before the POST. So it means the GPU is bad right? I find it weird that the mobo said that there is a missing graphic component. Isn't there an integrated graphics card already in all motherboards?

Comment: Yes, gfx card seems to be bad in this case. If you have a GFX connector on the back of your computer (blue VGA, white DVI or black HDMi or black DisplayPort), near where all the ports are (USB, audio, LAN) then yes, your computer HAS onboard GFX card and it seems to be turned off in BIOS. You could insert ANY graphic card (even an old PCI card that costs 1p) just to enter bios and turn on onboard gfx card. You could also reset BIOS entirely. Remember to plug monitor into appropriate connector on motherboard.

Comment: @Kitet, 
I swapped for an old GPU (5 years old)
It booted into BIOS,
But crashed when Windows start logo appears.
I tried to format the computer, but it crashes before entering Windows CD

Comment: @Kitet , No I tried with another GPU ( a new one gtx 770)
and it crashes before the POST.

Comment: Well then I can't say anything else that would bring something new to this discussion. At this point there's only replacing cpu and / or memory to see if something changes, if not - then it's motherboard. That's all of my ideas.

Comment: Try F8 and see if you can disable automatic restart.  If you get a stop code report the stop code or google it.